# Matlab vectorisation of loop "tracking value increments"

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have been breaking my head about trying to optimise a matlab script that needs to process quite long arrays.

Basically, there are 2 arrays: `AbsoluteTimeTag` and `Channel`.

`AbsoluteTimeTag` will hold int values signifying time that are recorded using a 16 bit counter. Since the counter is limited to 2^16 values it will often roll over during the course of the measurement. `Channel` registers this and when it does, `bitand(Channel,2048)` will evaluate true.

How these arrays are generated is out of my control and the overflow markers occur "in sync"  with the data coming in.

It is now easy to reconstruct the absolute time by doing:

```
AbsoluteTimeTag(i) = NoOfOverflows * 65536 + TimeTag(i);
```

In a loop:

```
for i=1:NumberOfRecords

    %Running through all records, if we meet anything other than an
    %overflow record, we van just calculate its absolute time based on
    %current overflow count and its timetag.
    AbsoluteTimeTag(i) = NoOfOverflows * 65536 + TimeTag(i);

    % We are running through all records so if we encounter an overflow
    % (signified by bitand(..., 2048), we add 1 to the overflow count.
    if bitand(Channel(i),2048)
        NoOfOverflows = NoOfOverflows + 1;
    end;
end;
```

I have been really breaking my head on how to potentially vectorise this (since Matlab is pretty bad at loops). So far however, I do not see the light for some reason.

Problem is that the number of overflows up to a certain record index along `AbsoluteTimeTag` can change as you walk the vector from start to end.

I do not know how I could express "count all occurrences of overflow up to this point" in a vectored operation.

Can somebody comment on whether or not this might be feasible at all?

**EDIT**

Example data would look like this:

TimeTag (each element is an event for which time is counted un a 2^3 register for simplicity):

```
[ 01 03 04 07 xx 02 03 04 05 xx 01 03 04 07 xx ... ]
```

overflow:

```
[ 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 ... ]
```

Which would need to yield

```
[ 01 03 04 07 xx 10 11 12 13 xx 17 19 20 23 xx ... ]
```

The reason xx is there is because originally, all records, both the events and the overflows are in one large uint32 array where each record holds different types of info on the different bits. The xx locations can undergo any operation but they are further meaningless when considering the TimeTag records. I have a logical array keeping track of what locations hold actual meaningful data.

Comment: Hi, I would eventually need to count the number of overflows. However, I need to perform the multiplication with the overflow count on each element of the time tag array using only the overflow occurrences "up to that point" if that makes any sense... I will amend the Q with example data...

Comment: So, for `xx locations`, the `AbsoluteTimeTag` values would be same as the corresponding `TimeTag` values? And are you saying that you have another array that tells us if the values are `xx` or not? If so, that would have the same number of elements as `AbsoluteTimeTag` and `Timetag`, right?

Comment: Hi Divakar, indeed, for the xx locations, I would just apply the same multiplication, i.e. 65536 * noOfOverflows (up to that point) + 16-bit timetag. Basically, these xx locations hold the 16 bit time tag of the overflow event itself whereas the other time tag locations are time tags of interesting events (photon detections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"count all occurrences of ... to this point" in a vectored operation` would be best expressed as **[`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html)**.

Assuming `NoOfOverflows` is initialized as zero before the start of the loop and `AbsoluteTimeTag`, `Timetag` have `NumberOfRecords` as their number of elements , see if this works for you -

```
%// Get the overflow for all Channel entries in one go
bitand_all = bitand(Channel,2048)~=0; 

%// AbsoluteTimeTag appears to be a cumsum of overflows plus Timetag
AbsoluteTimeTag = [0 ; cumsum(bitand_all(1:end-1).*65536)]+ TimeTag;

%// Get the count of overflows as NoOfOverflows
NoOfOverflows = sum(bitand_all);
```

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of cumsum... sometimes these things escape me completely. I' ll check this out. Thanks for the suggestion already.

Comment: @Kris So, for that `xx` locations thing, you need to add this at the end - `AbsoluteTimeTag(logical_array_xx_locations) = TimeTag`, where `logical_array_xx_locations` is the logical array with ones at the `xx` locations and zeros otherwise.

Comment: Hi Divakar, your solution worked like a charm, almost as is (the xx thing didn't matter). Output of your code is identical to the loop in Q. Many thanks good Sir! :)
One minor remark: to be able to sum `+ TimeTag` I needed to cast the array preceding + to uint32 since TimeTag itself was uint32.
In any case, I cannot help to be amazed at the succinctness of Matlab in some cases. Loops are horrible but vectorisation can be mighty fast.

Comment: @Kris Awesome! Well I thought that as well that `xx` won't needed, but I wasn't 100% sure about it, so put it as comment. Good point about class conversion!

Comment: @Kris Vectorization Rules!! ;) Well whenever it's possible (no dependency cases or depenedency cases where the dependency can be tracked), vectorization has to be tried on! :) For example in this case, we had dependency, but the dependency was a simple running sum, so it worked.